# TypeScript: generic interface as union of other interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, interface

I would like to create a generic interface with properties that represent a union of properties from other interfaces.

Let's say I have two interfaces

```
interface A {
    something: string;
    somethingElse: number;
}

interface B {
    something: Array<string>;
}
```

I do not want to write interface `C` as

```
interface C {
    something: string | Array<string>;
    somethingElse?: number;
}
```

because that would mean that whenever I modify either of the interfaces `A` or `B`, I would need to manually modify interface `C` as well.

From what I've seen in the TypeScript documentation as well as answers here on Stack Overflow, I should declare a new type

```
type unionOfKeys = keyof A | keyof B;
```

and implement generic interface form

```
interface GenericInterface {
    <T>(arg: T): T;
}
```

I was thinking in the direction of

```
interface C {
    <T extends unionOfKeys>(arg: T): T extends unionOfKeys ? A[T] | B[T] : any
}
```

but that fails because of mismatch between a number of properties and their types.

I would appreciate any sort of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following version of `MergeUnion<T>` might behave how you want:

```
type MergeUnion<T> = (
  keyof T extends infer K ? [K] extends [keyof T] ? Pick<T, K> & {
    [P in Exclude<(T extends any ? keyof T : never), K>]?:
    T extends Partial<Record<P, infer V>> ? V : never
  } : never : never
) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;

type C = MergeUnion<A | B>;
// type C = { 
//  something: string | string[]; 
//  somethingElse?: number | undefined; }
// }
```

This is similar to the other answer in that it finds the union of all keys of all the constituents of `T` (call it `UnionKeys`, defined as `T extends any ? keyof T : never`) and returns a mapped type with all of them in it.  The difference is that here we also find the intersection of all keys of all the constituents of `T` (call it `IntersectKeys`, defined as just `keyof T`) and split the keys `T` into two sets of keys.  The one from the intersection are present in every constituent, so we can just do `Pick<T, IntesectKeys>` to get the common properties.  The remainder, `Exclude<UnionKeys, IntersectKeys`> will be optional in the final type.

UPDATE 2019-08-23: the bug mentioned below seems to be fixed as of TS3.5.1

<strike>It's pretty ugly, and I'd clean it up if I felt better about it.  The problem is that there's still an issue when any of the properties appearing in all constituents are themselves optional.  There's a [bug in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20722) (as of TS3.5) where in `{a?: string} | {a?: number}`, the `a` property is seen as a *required* property like `{a: string | number | undefined}`, whereas it would be more correct to be treated as optional if any of the constituents have it as optional.  That bug bleeds through to `MergeUnion`:</strike>

```
type Oops = MergeUnion<{a?: string} | {a?: number}>
// type Oops =  { a: string | number | undefined; }
```

I don't have a great answer there that isn't even more complicated, so I'll stop here.

Maybe this is sufficient for your needs.  Or maybe @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's answer is sufficient for your needs.  Hope these answers help you; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIM4D2AthGABagDmAXPmFFQNw77GkUiUCiANnhLRABXIgCNozAL5YsoSLEQoAQphaES5KrVRQocAJ4AePPSoA+KTLD6ADigCy0ShACqIYARCGAKmeQBeZAAKFgBrCH0CGGRvZAgAD0gQABM8ZFAYaGQAaWQAfmQAbWyAXTjEiBS0wvDI6O8ygoAFYARQnwAaHL8AMlVcXEKm9JBkLniEHiFkiEMg2ISk1OQ4EH185FqomORBCAA3aABKLuyzErzqFlwFiqrkJrgoMGA4HkMAJQgEAihkwyaXQyWQAamY-AUQbtkCADtAWJJobDDlAkXCoFgjuUlmlgaiXBsMEVcqBNhFti4SrQXMUyoi9ijmFhrHZkABhALIRxQZxuDxedAAH2QSgsWAA9OLkCyUBzAkSJVLWBoODQ6AxOMhhSYNZRCiVGMhFbh1OwqLx+JcYSJxKjhUIUhAYKAIMlDdJJchpMzbCgAPIEGxpQLc3nuTyGDBwK06qiI4VRq3CMTQSRmY0y5ABoOczArWixzXC5O2rXIB0zZ2wt1emRAA)

Comment: This solves my problem entirely! Thank you so much for your time and effort, this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Neither intersection types or union types will get us to `C`. A union type (`A | B` will only allow access to common properties). An intersection (`A & B`) will allow access to all properties but if the properties disagree between `A` and `B` the property will be an intersection of the two properties ( ex `something` will be `string & Array<string>;` which is not very useful here).

The solution is to build a custom mapped type that will take keys from all types passed in and create a union of property types from each member:

```
interface A {
    something: string;
    somethingElse: number;
}

interface B {
    something: Array<string>;
}

type KeyOf<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type PropValue<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends Record<K, infer V> ? V : never;
type Merge<T> = {
    [P in KeyOf<T>] : PropValue<T, P>
}

type C = Merge<A | B>
// type C = {
//     something: string | string[];
//     somethingElse: number;
// }
```

`KeyOf` will take a `T` and if `T` is a union it will return keys of all union members. It does this using the distributive property of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```
type K = KeyOf<{a : number} | { b: number }> //  "a" | "b".
```

This is needed as `keyof` for a unuion will only return common members. (`keyof ({a : number} | { b: number })` is `never`).

`PropValue`also uses the distributive property of conditional types to extract a union of all value types for a key.

```
type V = PropValue<{a : number} | {a : string} |{ b: number }, 'a'> //  string | number
```

Putting it together in a mapped type we get `Merge` which maps over all keys in every member of the union and maps to a union of all possible property types.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a property to be optional in the output type if it's not present in all constituents of the input union.

Comment: @jcalz hm .. that's true... if you have a better version I don't mind deleting mine.. I'm preparing for a presentation tomorrow and I'd better not procrastinate too much with this 

Comment: Hi, unfortunately as @jcalz has stated, the output type should be optional if it's not present in all constituents of the input union, hence why I accepted his answer as correct. I would love to thank you for your time and effort, because this explanation was on point, and I will definitely save it somewhere! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @jcalz, for the great answer! I've modified it for better readability if anyone's interested. Also, the mentioned bug is now solved.

```
type Keys<TUnion> =
  TUnion extends unknown ? keyof TUnion : never;

type Values<TObject extends Object> = {
  [TKey in keyof TObject]: TObject[TKey];
};

//

type RequiredKeys<TUnion> =
  keyof TUnion;

type RequiredValues<TUnion> =
  Pick<TUnion, RequiredKeys<TUnion>>;

//

type OptionalKeys<TUnion> =
  Exclude<Keys<TUnion>, RequiredKeys<TUnion>>;

type OptionalValue<TUnion, TKey extends PropertyKey> =
  TUnion extends Partial<Record<TKey, infer TValue>> ? TValue : never;

type OptionalValues<TUnion> = {
  [TOptionalKey in OptionalKeys<TUnion>]?: OptionalValue<TUnion, TOptionalKey>;
};

//

export type Merge<TUnion> = Values<
  RequiredValues<TUnion> &
  OptionalValues<TUnion>
>;
```

---

```
type Test = Merge<
  | { a?: string; b: string; c: number; }
  | { a?: number; b: string[]; c?: number; }
>;

// type Test = {
//   a?: string | number | undefined;
//   b: string | string[];
//   c?: number | undefined;
// };
```