# Typescript: Omit a property from all interfaces in a union, but keep the union structure

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I have a few interfaces defined like so:

```js
interface A {
  toRemove: string;
  key1: "this1";
  key2: number;
}
interface B {
  toRemove: string;
  key1: "this2";
  key3: string;
}
```

And a union of both interfaces:

```js
type C = A|B;
```

What I want to do is to remove the `toRemove` key from both interfaces through C, something like this:

```js
type CC = Omit<A, "toRemove">|Omit<B, "toRemove">;
```

But without having to omit the key from both interfaces.
This would be ideal:

```js
type CC = Omit<C, "toRemove">;
```

But, unfortunately, `CC` will be of type `Pick<A|B, "key1">`, where `key1` is the key present in both interfaces.

In essence, what I'm trying to achieve is a type of "function" to transform:

```js
A1|A2|...|An
```

into:

```
Omit<A1, K keyof A1>|Omit<A1, K keyof A2>|...|Omit<An, K keyof An>
```

I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297816/6520174 and I have a feeling that part of what I need is somewhere in there, but I don't really understand what's going on in that code.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You want to *distribute* the `Omit` across a union. Luckily, you can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to achieve this:

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends any
  ? Omit<T, K>
  : never;
```

The `T extends any` construction looks like it doesn't do much, but since `T` is a type parameter, it distributes the conditional type across any union constituents of `T`.

Let's test it:

```
type CC = DistributiveOmit<C, "toRemove">;
// type CC = Pick<A, "key1" | "key2"> | Pick<B, "key1" | "key3">
```

You can verify that this is equivalent to the `CC` type you want.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLAewCUIBbfANwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkBrCATwEYaARGAAWwWrwFtcXbgCYaIAK4kARtDYBfLKEixEKAEKZ2BYmUo16jEK3Yz+yIaPGS7PAMyWGzTVixhuAAcUAGFkAF40ZAAfZAM2fyCUABExbxVFMGBKAHkSYDAAHgAVABpkAGlkCAAPSBAAE1pOHnwYZDgQbgA+CORi6rqIRubO7nYAfmQ8gpLyiu72BQhKKASA4OQQsMjUq2AMrNz8opDyoSJSCggBbrYAenu8JK2d5AAFYAQOQtRz+wEMUcMlktyBn2+hQM-x4EiBAhk7luWCAA)

Comment: I've set my editor to warn me on the use of any types and I believe that they can be removed in this case. Can `K extends keyof any` be replaced with `K extends keyof T`, and couldn't `T extends any` be replaces with `T extends T`, since it'll be resolved to `A extends T?... | B extends T?...`

Comment: You can replace `keyof any` with `PropertyKey` if you want; replacing it with `keyof T` may meet your use cases, but the [standard library's definition of `Omit`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1466-L1469) uses `keyof any` so that's why I used it.  As for `T extends any`, you probably could replace it with `T extends T` but I haven't used that construct.  I suspect it would be resolved to `A extends A ? ... | B extends B ? ...`.  My instinct would be to use `T extends unknown` instead.

Comment: `PropertyKey` and `T extends unknown` are perfect ! Even though the standard library uses `keyof any`, I'll use this just to remove properties from types/interfaces, so `PropertyKey` will suffice. I'm going to read more on the implications of using `unknown`. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @jcalz Why is this not working ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAwhAdgM2AHM4BfOfKCEOAIhgENgAbAd2FwBMBjAZ19oBuAFDCkqOABFgvGFGAAjAK4xgANxQB5EMBgAeACoAaOAGk4KAB4wUXXnADWKRBHxwGuRAD44AXjgGFta2nPYeiMJwcAD8cNq6hiamXpFwAFxwuCgaUCLCAPT5cADqaKwe8CgM3AAWcGDVDgxEaDAQcApoUCi8kLi8isxo+NBwuvYQrLhwAAbceDa4MDMAdGLIaADKNQzdnDgExH5SMnKKKupaOvoHhEQmtPNLtjC0KcJPsu4Z27so+3g7sd0KlCnAAHJ4FDCUjCIA

Answer (score -2):

Another approach is:

```
export declare type Without<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

```
type CC = Without<A, "toRemove">| Without<B, "toRemove">;
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't do, your `Without` is basically Typescript's `Omit`. I also said in the question: `without having to omit the key from both interfaces`. Clearly, your solution requires removing the key from both interfaces.