# Property does not exist after union and extended Omit

Tags: typescript

I have a base `Type` that is extended upon by two interfaces. I then have another interface which is a `Union` of the two Types.

Later on I process these type to replace the `Number` date property which an actual `Date` object, so I have a type for that too.

However, upon trying to read the `lens` property in my component (after a condition I thought should differentiate it as a `Camera`, I get an error.

`Property 'lens' does not exist on type 'DatedDevice'.`

```
export enum DeviceType {
  Camera = 'camera-device',
  Phone = 'phone-device'
}

interface DeviceBase {
  id: string;
  date: number;
}

export interface Camera extends DeviceBase {
  lens: string;
  type: DeviceType.Camera;
}

export interface Phone extends DeviceBase {
  receiver: string;
  type: DeviceType.Phone;
}

// Union of two extended interfaces
export type Device = Camera | Phone;

// Type for replacing number with Date
export interface DatedDevice extends Omit<Device, 'date'> {
  date: Date;
}

// Error in component.
// 'device' is a prop of type 'DatedDevice'
if (device.type === DeviceType.Text) {
  console.log(device.lens);
  // ^ Property 'lens' does not exist on type 'DatedDevice'

}
```

Comment: What's the variable device?

Comment: @zixiCat It's a prop of type 'DatedDevice'. I've edited this into the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57103940/8605960), you need to use [distributive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types)

Unfortunately I can't add an in depth explanation of the solution other than that your `Omit` doesn't work like you expect

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends any
  ? Omit<T, K>
  : never;
  
export type DatedDevice = DistributiveOmit<Device, 'date'> & {
  date: Date;
}

if (device.type === DeviceType.Camera) {
  console.log(device.lens);
} else {
  console.log(device.receiver)
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you!