# TypeScript: Extract then Omit from union

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a `Vehicle` union type that looks like that:

```js
interface Car {
  color: string;
  doors: number;
  wheels: number;
}

interface Plane {
  color: string;
  wings: number;
}

type Vehicle = Car | Plane;
```

I want (1) to extract from this union the types that extend a given type argument (this can easily be achieved using the `Extract` utility type) and (2) to omit from the extracted type(s) the keys of that same type argument. Here's the desired output:

```js
type Result1 = ExtractOmit<{ wheels: number; }>;
// This should give me the result of Omit<Car, "wheels">:
// { color: string; doors: number; }

type Result2 = ExtractOmit<{ wings: number; }>;
// This should give me the result of Omit<Plane, "wings">:
// { color: string; }

type Result3 = ExtractOmit<{ foo: number; }>;
// This should produce an error since foo is neither in Car nor Plane
```

Here's an unsuccessful attempt:

```js
type ExtractOmit<T> = Omit<Extract<Vehicle, T>, keyof T>;
// T extends what?
```

The right part seems right to me but I can't figure out how to put up the left one.

Any suggestion?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGchAewBtCoAuZAZzClAHMBuPZAE0LKspAFcBbAEbRm+AO4ALCBGJdkvQcJwBfHDlCRYiFAAVicEClz4ipCtVoMRyUQ1nyhUZipxgAngAcUANQjjgCYhQAXjQMZAAfZF19CGYXDxQAUQAPWkQwAHk+YDAAHgAVAD5kEKyc3JS0hDyfPwCIABpkIqaAawhXQhhmwri3T2QAJQgqHmIwAEYS5EqodLK8rGtJaTt+B0ZkJV6cAHpd5r8qazJWqlV+lGHR8YAmadn57MXrW2514S2d-cPgY9FTud4gNrmMwABmB6pObVBa5JYwDjvBSOL7MH75I7UcSEMasZDuKCEVg8JDIfTIaBEzBUUBkxGEZB-OQQHKSTCgUKYEBkKJ6AyqIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Car {
    color: string;
    doors: number;
    wheels: number;
}

interface Plane {
    color: string;
    wings: number;
}

type Vehicle = Car | Plane;

type OmitExtract<T extends Partial<Vehicle>> = Omit<Extract<Vehicle, T>, keyof T>;

type Result = OmitExtract<{ wheels: number; }>;

type Result1 = OmitExtract<{ wheels: number; }>;
// This should give me the result of Omit<Car, "wheels">:
// { color: string; doors: number; }

type Result2 = OmitExtract<{ wings: number; }>;
// This should give me the result of Omit<Plane, "wings">:
// { color: string; }
```

The above seems to work as expected.

The key pieces here being using "Vehicle" (I noticed you used Element earlier) and having T extend the Partial on the left to give it the supertype necessary for Extract to know what to extract from correctly.

Edit: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5BAewBsioAuZAZzClAHMBuPAgEyPOqpAFcBbAEbQWBZAHcAFhAgluyPkJE4AvjhyhIsRCgAKJOCBS4xxMpRp1GoguMbzFwqCzU4wATwAOKAGoRJwAgkKAC8aBjIAD7I%20oYQLG5eKADy-MBgAKIAHnSIYAA8ACrIEDkQIGzUMRhgwHAk%20X4BQRAAfK3IYanp%20dm5CAVNgcEANMiFrWMA1hDuRDDjrQke3sgAShDUvCRgncjdmTlQeflYEtKyDgJOTMgqS%20orKBtbOwCMewd9xwOn5zJyHjXER3B4AejB4wCVWokiI2zYyAYwAAbih%20CgwNJkFBNttdvN9mkCugoGMAERSAHUcmtCg4CHYQikchUWj0EDMZAcLhApTOO6PJLrPE7ABMn2J3xOZzsnKu-Nu9xYjMK0JocIRSNR6Mx2NxrwJCwO%20ViRgpcoYNLpDMhZzMrMsHK5KiAA)

Comment: You actually don't even need the "T extends Partial<Vehicle>" unless you just really want to restrict the typing of T's supertype. Having Vehicle on the right hand side is what's most important to setup the Extract utility type.

Comment: You need to use `type Vehicle = Car | Plane;` as per OP's post. OP's original playground had the wrong code with `type Vehicle = Car & Plane` which will give the wrong result as in your playground. Union is what's needed on Vehicle to setup Vehicle appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, sorry for the confusion with `Element`, I meant `Vehicle` as you guessed.

Comment: I noticed there's one edge case that's not covered by this. It's when `{ color: string; }` is passed as an argument. Since both `Car` and `Plane` extend `{ color: string; }`, I'd expect the result to be a union of those (from which `color` would be omitted): `{ doors: number; wheels: number; } | { wings: number; }`. But all I get is `{}`. Any idea how we might take this case into account?

Comment: Ok all we need is a distributive Omit (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103834/typescript-omit-a-property-from-all-interfaces-in-a-union-but-keep-the-union-s).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGchAewBtCoAuZAZzClAHMBuPZAE0LKspAFcBbAEbRm+AO4ALCBGJdkvQcJwBfHDlCRYiFAAVicEClz4ipCtVoMRyUQ1nyhUZipxgAngAcUANQjjgCYhQAXjQMZAAfZF19CGYXDxQAEWAaOgEeMGAANwgAeT5gMAAeABUAGmQAaWQIAA9IEFYqZABrCFdCGGR9VwA+ZBCSmvqIRuaelgB+ZHzC0orK3pZuCBzHVTdPZABReqhEMFniobqGpqiMTLhiIp8-AIhe-pDk1OB0zJyjot3aA9vfP5AhUSr0Km0Ol1QXFNigAEoQKg8YhgACMAx2ewO3yw1kk0js-AcjGQSl6zAA9BTkCU-M0UsNPAhIKwNglkAikSiAEwY377Zk46y2bhE4Sk8k4Kk0unIBl1JkstlbTnIsAAZj5WMFBWKuJgHFFCkcEsp1NpDPltUVEFZ8RViLVABYtX8dXNcSYyJQ3iB6KapebZVabaygA

Comment: Was just about to post the same after coming across the stackoverflow thread! Hope that worked. Learning a lot more about ts' utility types today haha

Comment: In general, I've found that there are a lot of places in which typescript doesn't allow good Union splitting (i.e. dealing with an explicit "A | B" as a type when it comes to checking equality/assignments).