# automatically create a type without $case

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert some types. I have a "union" type of this kind

```js
interface A {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

interface B {
    b: number;
    c: string[];
}

type Orig = {
    $case: 'a';
    a: A;
} | {
    $case: 'b';
    b: B;
}
```

and I would like to convert it in a more "compact" form, basically removing the `$case`

```js
type Goal = {
    a: A;
} | {
    b: B;
}
```

But I don't want to "write" the `Goal` type by hand, I would like to have it as a depended type, maybe using `Record` / `Exclude` / `Omit` etc.. but I had no luck :/

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20XALmRAFcBbAI2gG4c8KiBnMKUAc1oF8stRJZEKAEKY6uBsXJUotPMgRMW7ANoBdLjzABPAA4oA8qzbIAvKLkASBHEYQiAcjj3ZeQmi7IAPubxWbd5HsKZzFkCSENLG09ZABxAHs4ABtTH1w3VA9vbDlwyIR4kGZkeKMAfQgADzgyHSSAw2BjMxzfa1sHJwAaULdWuXSiAEYAJgBmHoH6TooEe1DuTlosAqKwZDZEpIrq2vqiBOTU-vwiE7k3UYnQ3Jm5hawlzV0UABUIcDgwYAA3FDMAEoQApQAAmAB4AKKVBBJEigiDggDWEC08RgyEabC6gT8tnsAD4cXAQFoCcsVoVipBPt8-jsanUAu9ab9-hstgy9hBaKtqRBmActqkaWAvmyuUzqEA) is the playground with also my tentatives

Comment: You're looking for "distributive `Omit`", as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6xMym) and in the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103834/typescript-omit-a-property-from-all-interfaces-in-a-union-but-keep-the-union-s).