# Typescript generics: readonly values from interface children

Tags: typescript, generics

Given this input:

```js
export type Test = {
    one: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        c: string;
    };
    two: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        d: string;
    };
}
```

I need a generics like `CombinedChildren<T>` which outputs the following type:

```js
export type Combined = {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
    d?: string;
}
```

Basically, it takes the children properties and combines them, *including them even if they're not present in all children*.

Tried

```js
export type KeyOfTest = Partial<Test[keyof Test]>
export type MappedKeyOfTest = Partial<{
    [key in keyof Test[keyof Test]]: Test[keyof Test][key]
}>
```

But none output exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to also merge all types for example string | number then here is a solution

```
export type Test = {
    one: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        c: string;
    };
    two: {
        a: number;
        b: string;
        d: string;
    };
    three: {
      a: string;
      e: number;
    }
}

type AllNested = Test[keyof Test]

type KeyOf<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never

type PropValue<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends Record<K, infer V> ? V : never

type Merged<T> = {
    [P in KeyOf<T>] : PropValue<T, P>
}

type MergedType = Merged<AllNested>
```

Link to the
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDO8C8cDeAUHCXBAHbABcBxp9AhjdlAJbkDmA3HfSQEbMYbTjz6kAxkJHdecAL5jSMAO4QaRcSSZxyAVwC2-YFCXjBcFu1la4AE2nWzC5zAAWUYNVridV0XIk3vpGJs7yhBGESChwAIIANgkAclgwwHZweBjYANoA1sCIEABm6GkAuoTRyKgA0kUA8iUAPGgAfFnocKDp5HaYcAzkiHAA-HCFxWVocDSUAG4m1TGoAApQEGAAagwJesBtADRwdT0gfQNwG1smSA2Indnnl4MASsAS0HYtdSfsJRMcG2nQm2zmumASygK1qcAAsiYOBk2k8fKRcms4OxTk1Wh0KhCbjs9gdjtd2pFYbFEVBkXY0HC8LT6S1Eik0hlKUA)

Solution is based on this brilliant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56296734/2983577)

Answer (score 3):

We can break this down into a few steps. First, we get a union of all the child types by `Test[keyof Test]`. Then we want a union of all this type, so we use a utility type that converts union types to intersection types ([taken from this answer by @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/8580499)). Finally, we apply `Partial` to the resulting type.

```
export type Test = {
    one: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        c: string;
    };
    two: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        d: string;
    };
    three: {
      a: string;
      e: number;
    }
}

// union to intersection converter by @jcalz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/8580499
// Intersect<{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }> = { a: 1 } & { b: 2 }
type Intersect<T> = (T extends any ? ((x: T) => 0) : never) extends ((x: infer R) => 0) ? R : never;

// Combined = { a?: string; b?: string; c?: string; d?: string; e?: number }
type Combined = Partial<Intersect<Test[keyof Test]>>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDO8C8cDeAUHCXBAHbABcBxp9AhjdlAJbkDmA3HfSQEbMYbTjz6kAxkJHdecAL5jSMAO4QaRcSSZwW7WVriDdw-UvEATaWbmK5MABZRg1WuJ17Rckq-IBXAFt+YChzBUJ5QkIAemi4P3JWCgQIOHYYEMxgCRgk8jgJCgA3EIyoI0Q4AAEAKwkGABsALxoHGBgwTCpY7AYJAGsIEqgAMwaIFQA6QoDohmiAVgAGAGYAdgWAJgAOADZo7YXtpYAWAE4zmLiASXIyrJyAHnw4HQBGBTgAHwIjGk2FAA+OB4F7vT4AMl+xgBkSQKDgt3u2RgjzQwLwAAo0HBQBlyBZMK9yJUAPxwTGYkA0NAAShBwKW9JolGG9LxwAJRMp1LS5BGITgACV6ThGfTyUK4CzgMMeFc4ABhCBBdjACwg34MUnWURGHUmGRcAoGzzcOAWU2mPXAA3+IKCuHIVDK1WUDV4AAKDFgrEajyRmRRaKwMAA2v1gIgICN0KGALqAwE8IA)

Comment: This might not be working as expected due to conflicts between types. Try changing in second object type of a to number for example. The result would be a?: undefined

Comment: @ZZB I don't think there's any reasonable output in that case without a more detailed specification. Do we want `a?: string | number` or do we omit `a`, or something else?

Comment: It would be interesting to see an answer with merged types like "string" | "number". I have tried to do it however it turned out to be more tricky than I thought

Comment: Here is an answer to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296506/typescript-generic-interface-as-union-of-other-interfaces